# Applying fourier transform twice (DSP course)

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft

I stumbled upon a question in a DSP course (coursera) which I don't understand, shown below is a screenshot of the question and answer.
[image]

The part which I don't understand is circled. Why is it equal to 0? For multiples of N I understand that each element in the summation is 1 because the exponent is 0. But why does the summation equal 0 when (i+n) is not a multiple of N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [formula for the geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}kl}=\frac{1-e^{-j2\pi l}}{1-e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}l}},\qquad l\neq mN,\;m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Now realize that $e^{-j2\pi l}=1$ for $l\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the result follows.